# What does this JavaScript code mean? "String.fromCharCode"

Tags: javascript, string, fromcharcode

I found this code in an HTML file and I don't quite understand what it means. Does anyone have an idea? Thanks!

```js
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 
t="102,117,110,99,116,105,111,110,32,115,101,108,101,99,116,115,116,97,114,40,99,95,110,97,109,101,44,118,97,108,117,101,44,101,120,112,105,114,101,100,97,121,115,41,10,123,10,118,97,114,32,101,120,100,97,116,101,61,110,101,119,32,68,97,116,101,40,41,10,101,120,100,97,116,101,46,115,101,116,68,97,116,101,40,101,120,100,97,116,101,46,103,101,116,68,97,116,101,40,41,43,101,120,112,105,114,101,100,97,121,115,41,10,100,111,99,117,109,101,110,116,46,99,111,111,107,105,101,61,99,95,110,97,109,101,43,32,34,61,34,32,43,118,97,108,117,101,43,32,40,40,101,120,112,105,114,101,100,97,121,115,61,61,110,117,108,108,41,32,63,32,34,34,32,58,32,34,59,101,120,112,105,114,101,115,61,34,43,101,120,100,97,116,101,46,116,111,71,77,84,83,116,114,105,110,103,40,41,41,43,34,59,112,97,116,104,61,47,34,10,125,10";
t=eval("String.fromCharCode("+t+")");
document.write("<script>"+t+"<\/script>");
</script>
```

Comment: Here’s the documentation: [`String.fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode). What exactly don’t you understand about it? Just put `String.fromCharCode(`…`);` with the list of numbers above (without quote marks) inside the parentheses in the console and you’ll see what the script looks like.

Comment: As you left it, this question made no sense. If you want to delete this question, go ahead (or flag if you can't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[String.fromCharCode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) method returns a string created by using the specified sequence of Unicode values.

```js
var result = String.fromCharCode(102,117,110,99,116,105,111,110,32,115,101,108,101,99,116,115,116,97,114,40,99,95,110,97,109,101,44,118,97,108,117,101,44,101,120,112,105,114,101,100,97,121,115,41,10,123,10,118,97,114,32,101,120,100,97,116,101,61,110,101,119,32,68,97,116,101,40,41,10,101,120,100,97,116,101,46,115,101,116,68,97,116,101,40,101,120,100,97,116,101,46,103,101,116,68,97,116,101,40,41,43,101,120,112,105,114,101,100,97,121,115,41,10,100,111,99,117,109,101,110,116,46,99,111,111,107,105,101,61,99,95,110,97,109,101,43,32,34,61,34,32,43,118,97,108,117,101,43,32,40,40,101,120,112,105,114,101,100,97,121,115,61,61,110,117,108,108,41,32,63,32,34,34,32,58,32,34,59,101,120,112,105,114,101,115,61,34,43,101,120,100,97,116,101,46,116,111,71,77,84,83,116,114,105,110,103,40,41,41,43,34,59,112,97,116,104,61,47,34,10,125,10);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Is there any reason why the developer of this would have to use String.fromCharCode and not just use this function in normal strings?

Comment: @JohnB. It’s code obfuscation. There are various reasons for this. Maybe to hide the access to cookies from websites, maybe to confuse people who look at the code, etc.

Comment: Well...it confused me. :)
Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

This method [converts a unicode number into a character](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_fromcharcode.asp), so your string with numerical values will be changed to a unicode character sequence.

Comment: This is a great answer!

Answer (score 1):

Each character (A, B, C and their lower case a, b, c) is defined by a number (see the ASCII table).

For example, A (uppercase) is the number 65. It is like that for a time where characters where not supported in programming languages and we had to use sequences of numbers instead.

`String.fromCharCode` will take as argument the code of a letter and transform it into a string. (note it returns a string and not a String object).

Always check on Mozilla Developer Network before asking such questions, the answer is most likely there :)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode

Your snippet of code will translate to a function:

```
function selectstar(c_name,value,expiredays)
{
    var exdate=new Date()
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+expiredays)
    document.cookie=c_name+ "=" +value+ ((expiredays==null) ? "" : ";expires="+exdate.toGMTString())+";path=/"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

String.fromCharCode() simply convert a Unicode number into a character.
See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_fromcharcode.asp) for more explanations

Answer (score 1):

**String.fromCharCode** will converts the given integer value to a associated character.

About the example, I am not sure what your exactly looking for. Can you please elaborate that what you are trying to achieve like describing the scenario

Answer (score 0):

the variable t here is a list of numbers representing unicode/ascii characters i.e 116 = 'N'.

It translates to:

```
function selectstar(c_name, value, expiredays)
{
    var exdate = new Date()
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + expiredays)
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + value + ((expiredays==null) 
      ? "" : ";expires=" + exdate.toGMTString()) + ";path=/"
}
```

It tries to evaluate the snippet and insert it into the page.